# what is text='<%#eval()>' in the html tags?

Tags: html

Yet i have not realized what is the diffrence between this two statement in HTML:

```
text='<%#Eval("some thing")>'

text='<%#Bind("some thing")>'
```

Comment: EVal is one way binding, Bind is two way

If you bind a value using Eval, it is like a read only. You can only view the data.

If you bind a value using Bind, and if you do some change on the value it will reflect on the database also

Comment: That is not a part of HTML, that's the server side language inserted inside HTML

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the examplke on MSDN, in this case using a repeater

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

also

> How to: Bind to Data in a Templated Control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95k0273d(v=vs.80).aspx